# Merge Sort stops before displaying the sorted array

Tags: c++, mergesort

I was trying to code Merge Sort using the algorithm, given in my textbook.
I did exactly as shown but the program stops after MergeSort function is called.
[This is an image of the output when I executed it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp8M0.png)
It is printing the unsorted array fine but omits everything after function call in line 16.

Please Help!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[10] = {23,13,41,27,55,83,12,65,11,20};
int b[10];
void MergeSort(int,int);
void Merge(int,int,int);

int main(){
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    cout<<"array beffore sorting:";
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    MergeSort(0,9);
    for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++);
    cout<<"After Sorting:";
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }

}
void MergeSort(int l, int h){
    if(l<h){
        int mid = (l+h)/2;

        MergeSort(l,mid);
        MergeSort(mid,h);
        Merge(l,mid,h);
    }
    
}

void Merge(int low, int mid, int high){
    int h = low;
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;

    while(h<=mid && j<=high){
        if(a[h]<a[j]){
            b[i] = a[h];
            h++;

        }
        else{
            b[i] = a[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(h>mid){
        for(int k= j; k<=high; k++){
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int k= h; k<=mid; k++){
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(int k= low; k<=high; k++){
            a[k] = b[k];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: think about what happens in `MergeSort` if `l` is `0` and `h` is `1`

Comment: my bad, i missed that logic bad!! Thanks !!!

Comment: Are you on an embedded system using `for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++);` loop for a delay loop? That would certainly cause a "stop" before displaying the output. You may want to at least add comments to indicate what unusual looking parts of your code do.

Comment: yea that was not necessary apparently the problem was in the MergeSort() function.

Answer (score 1):

I made an error int the logic of MergeSort function got the answer!!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[10] = {23,13,41,27,55,83,12,65,11,20};
int b[10];
void MergeSort(int,int);
void Merge(int,int,int);

int main(){
    int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    cout<<"array beffore sorting:";
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    MergeSort(0,9);
    cout<<"After Sorting:";
    for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }

}
void MergeSort(int l, int h){
    if(l<h){
        int mid = (l+h)/2;

        MergeSort(l,mid);
        MergeSort(mid+1,h);
        Merge(l,mid,h);
    }
}

void Merge(int low, int mid, int high){
    int h = low;
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;

    while(h<=mid && j<=high){
        if(a[h]<a[j]){
            b[i] = a[h];
            h++;

        }
        else{
            b[i] = a[j];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(h>mid){
        for(int k= j; k<=high; k++){
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int k= h; k<=mid; k++){
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(int k= low; k<=high; k++){
            a[k] = b[k];
    }
    
}
```